# react-router-v6 nested "Route" working on localhost but not on Cpanel

Tags: reactjs, react-router, cpanel, react-router-dom, nested-routes

I am new to react and just learnt react-router-v6.

I wrote nested code for react-router-v6 which is actually **working perfectly on Localhost** but as soon as I am uploading the build on Cpanel (.htaccess file is already there), elements with **nested "Route" takes us to a blank page**.

[*Browse [here](https://condescending-morse-5acfb7.netlify.app/) and click "Safe Defi" in navbar*].

This is My App.Js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Bottomnav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="faqs" element={<Faqs />} />
          <Route path="safedefi" element={<Pagesafedefi />} >
            <Route path="projectowner" element={<Ownercards />} />
            <Route path="influencers" element={<Influencers />} />
            <Route path="developers" element={<Devcards />} />
            <Route path="promoters" element={<Promoters />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/safedefi/projectowner/ownerprofile" element={<Ownerprofile />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here Route with path safedefi is taking us to blank screen while it is working perfectly on Localhost.

Comment: I see a 404 page not found when attempting to navigate to `"/safedefi"`.

Answer (score 0):

here problem in your code

[image]

My be in your code some where you data getting null.